# How to accept and reject (Ack and Nack) messages manually?

Tags: asp.net-core, easynetq

I create a consumer base to retrieve each message from RabbitMq. I'm using easynetq to consume the messages in which the consumer is configured by advanced mode because the queue has some different configurations. Once recevied a message a call async method to process each message. However, the consume method in the advanced doesn't have a async consume method. Do I have to call async method using Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew methods?

Some process may last long time and erros may occurs during the process. In the error cases, I need to reject the message and let the message into the queue again. When the process is finally complete successfully, the message can accept and remove it from the queue.

That's an example of my code:

```
var queue = _bus.Advanced.QueueDeclare(_queueName, durable: true);
            _consumerResult = _bus.Advanced.Consume(queue, (body, properties, info) =>
            {
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                    return;

                var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IntegrationEvent<T>>(message, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                    TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
                });

                deserializeObject.DeliveryTag = info.DeliverTag;

                // I need to call a async method               
                ConsumeAsync(deserializeObject));

            });
```

How I can accept and reject the message manually?